# How to use getoptlong class in ruby?

Tags: ruby, getopt-long

I need help using getoptlong class in Ruby. I need to execute command prog_name.ruby -u -i -s filename. So far I can only execute it with prog_name.ruby -u filename -i filename -s filename.

This is my getoptlong code:

```
require 'getoptlong'

class CommonLog
parser = GetoptLong.new
parser.set_options(["-h", "--help", GetoptLong::NO_ARGUMENT],
                   ["-u", "--url",  GetoptLong::NO_ARGUMENT],
                   ["-i", "--ip",   GetoptLong::NO_ARGUMENT],
                   ["-s", "--stat", GetoptLong::NO_ARGUMENT])

begin
  begin
      opt,arg = parser.get_option
      break if not opt

      case opt
         when "-h" || "--help"
           puts "Usage: -u  filename"
           puts "Usage: -i  filename"
           puts "Usage: -s  filename"
         exit
         when "-u" || "--url"
            log = CommonLog.new(ARGV[0])
            log.urlReport
         when "-i" || "--ip"
            log = CommonLog.new(ARGV[0])
            log.ipReport
         when "-s" || "--stat"
            log = CommonLog.new(ARGV[0])
            log.statReport
         end
      rescue => err
         puts "#{err.class()}: #{err.message}"
         puts "Usage: -h -u -i -s filename"
      exit
   end
end while 1

if ARGV[0] == nil || ARGV.size != 1
   puts "invalid! option and filename required"
   puts "usage: -h -u -i -s filename"
end
```

Comment: `begin/end` inside a `begin/end while 1` block? o_O How about `loop`?

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to answer by recommending looking at the new-ish "[slop](https://github.com/injekt/slop)" gem. It's a wrapper around `getoptlong`.

You can use `gem install slop` if you're using RVM, or `sudo gem install slop` otherwise.

GetOptLong is very powerful but, though I've used it several times, I still have to go review the docs each time.

If you want a bit more power, with an "easier to use interface than GetOptLong", look into Ruby's [`OptionParser`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/index.html). You'll need to work out the logic better, but this is a quick pass converting your code. I had to stub out a class for the CommonLog gem because I don't use it. The important stuff follows the line pulling log from `ARGV`:

```
require 'optparse'

class CommonLog
  def initialize(*args); end
  def urlReport();     puts "running urlReport()";        end
  def ipReport();      puts "running ipReport()";         end
  def statReport(arg); puts "running statReport(#{arg})"; end
end

log = CommonLog.new(ARGV[0])

OptionParser.new { |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: #{File.basename($0)} -u -i -s filename"

  opts.on( '-u', '--[no-]url', 'some short text describing URL') do
    log.urlReport()
  end

  opts.on('-i', '--[no-]ip', 'some short text describing IP') do
    log.ipReport()
  end

  opts.on('-s', '--stat FILENAME', 'some short text describing STAT') do |arg|
    log.statReport(arg)
  end
}.parse!
```

Also, as a quick critique, you are not writing idiomatic Ruby code:

- `when` statements can be written: `when "-h", "--help"`
- `if ARGV[0] == nil || ARGV.size != 1` is convoluted. Study up on how ARGV and arrays work. Normally, for `ARGV[0]` to be nil there will be no more arguments, so `ARGV.empty?` would probably suffice.

Comment: optparser > getoptlong. Definitely.

Answer (score 0):

> you have several errors in the sample program
>
> 1. #each and #get only return the first string in the option and convert the others to it.
> 2. You should put that check for arguments before the options processing
> 3. You probably don't want this in with your logging class

```
require 'getoptlong'
# don't pollute CommonLog with this
include CommonLog
# if this is the startup module
if __FILE__ == $0 then
  # Check to ensure there are arguments
  if ARGV.size < 1
    puts "invalid! option and filename required"
    puts "usage: -h -u -i -s filename"
  end
  # set up parser and get the options
  parser_opts=GetoptLong.new(
    ["--help", "-h", GetoptLong::NO_ARGUMENT],
    ["--url", "-u", GetoptLong::NO_ARGUMENT],
    ["--ip", "-i", "--ip", GetoptLong::NO_ARGUMENT],
    ["--stat", "-s", GetoptLong::NO_ARGUMENT]
  )

  parser_opts.each do |opt,arg|
    begin # this is for the exception processing
      case opt
      when "--help" #only the first option is returned read ruby doc on #each
        puts "Usage: -u  filename"
        puts "Usage: -i  filename"
        puts "Usage: -s  filename"
        exit
      when "--url" #only the first option is returned
        log = CommonLog.new(ARGV[0])
        log.urlReport
      when "--ip" #only the first option is returned
        log = CommonLog.new(ARGV[0])
        log.ipReport
      when "--stat" #only the first option is returned
        log = CommonLog.new(ARGV[0])
        log.statReport
      else # this should not be used
        puts "unexpected option %s"%opt 
        puts "Usage: -h -u -i -s filename"
      end
    rescue Exception => err #rescuing an unexpected Exception
      puts "#{err.class()}: #{err.message}"
      puts "Usage: -h -u -i -s filename"
      Kernel.exit
    end
  end
end
```